# Efficient way to find eigenvalues of complex symmetric matrix with real off-diagonal elements

Tags: matrix, algorithms, eigenvalues, libraries, arpack

My goal is to find all eigenvalues (and eigenvectors) in a given range of magnitudes of a complex symmetric matrix with real off-diagonal elements (only diagonal elements are complex). Currently I'm using PARPACK for non-hermitian matrices and discard eigenvalues outside of the window of interest, but this method is more general than I need. Moreover, PARPACK only lets you use a maximum of `matrix_size / NCV` processors (NCV is proportional to the desired number of eigenvalues), but even within this limitation it does not scale efficiently. Do you know any algorithm or library that can take advantage of these restrictions and do better than PARPACK? Or at least scale better than PARPACK?

Comment: The eigenvalue problem just does not scale well with process count - some algorithms just don't parallelise well. Can you give us an idea of the matrix size  and number of processors you are using?

Comment: @IanBush My matricies are typically from 10000 to 1000000 (they are sparse though, so matrix-vector multiplication does not take long). The number of processors typically ranges from 8 to 96, depending on how many eigenvalues I need. Due to the restriction that I specified in the post, If I need more eigenvalues I have to use less processors, which makes the task even harder.

Comment: I'm not limited to 96 processors though, the supercomputer I'm using has many more, I just don't use them because PARPACK is not particularly efficient with them (and because of the restriction).

Comment: Check out SLEPc

Comment: I would try something like FEAST, where you can define a region in the complex plane in which you are interested.

Comment: Out of curiousity, where did this matrix come from? I haven't seen that complex-diagonal/real-offdiagonal structure before.

Comment: @rchilton1980 This matrix is a Hamiltonian matrix used to find ro-vibrational energy levels for a given system of atoms. Typically such matrices are Hermitian (or even real symmetric, as in my case). However, in addition to the energy levels, we are also interested in their respective lifetimes and for this we add a so-called complex absorbing potential (CAP), which makes the main diagonal of the Hamiltonian complex. In this case, the imaginary part of the eigenvalues can be used to calculate the lifetime of a given state.